# joomla lost data in jos_session

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, joomla2.5

```
$session = JFactory::getSession();
$session->set('domain_name', $domain_name, 'dominiForm');
```

then the table jos_session contains `...__dominiForm|a:2:{s:11:"domain_name";s:16:"safafasfsadfsfds";s:15:"tld_da_comprare";a:1:{i:0;s:3:".com";}}`

I have checked that session life is 45mins in joomla control panel.

However without using `set()` or `clear()` it randomly(i think after a few minutes of pause) when i click "next" i end up with the database containing only this `...__dominiForm|a:0:{}`

This happends both with 1.5 and 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem exists with parts of the code that you haven't shown. It sounds like the $session->set() is getting called during a point when you aren't expecting it to be called, and it is empty at that point so it is overwriting the stored value with an empty value. Post more of your code and I may be able to point out where the issue is.

Comment: i fixed it by reimplemting myself a sort of session in the databases, which magically doesn't disappear